# Different Scoped Properties - Public getter and internal setter

Tags: c#, properties, access-modifiers, internal

I know you can do this

```
public String<T> Get { get; private set; }
```

The problem is I want the set method to be accessible from a different class within the same DLL (ie: internal)

Is this possible?

Comment: To sidetrack a little bit, string is a non-generic type so you can't add <T> to it.

Comment: Yeah, what Bablo said. I didn't suspect anything at first when the code was unindented and `<T>` was hidden, but after indenting it I'm surprised to find it there.

Comment: This is surely a duplicate. Did you search before asking?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can use any access modifier with either automatic property accessor:

```
public String<T> Get { get; internal set; }
```